# Output is not visible in the console after optimizing the python code using multiprocessing

Tags: python, optimization, time, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to optimize my code using multiprocessing module of python. With added time stamp I can see that the time is reducing considerably for the optimized code, however i am unable to see the output on the console.

**Before Optimization my code is** ---

```
 import time
def counter1(num):
    cnt = 0
    for _ in range(num):
        cnt += 1
    print("counter 1 done")
    
def counter2(num):
    cnt = 0
    for _ in range(0,num,2):
        cnt += 1
    print("counter 2 done")
    
    
N = 2 * 10**8

#singleprocessing
st = time.time()
counter1(N)
counter2(N)
en = time.time()
print("time taken = ", en - st)
```

**whose output i got was**

```
counter 1 done
counter 2 done
time taken =  20.462417602539062
```

**My optimized code was ---**

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def counter1(num):
    cnt = 0
    for _ in range(num):
        cnt += 1
    print("counter 1 done")
    
def counter2(num):
    cnt = 0
    for _ in range(0,num,2):
        cnt += 1
    print("counter 2 done")
    
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    N = 2 * 10**8
    #singleprocessing
    st = time.time()
    counter1(N)
    counter2(N)
    en = time.time()
    print("time taken = ", en - st)##
    
    #multiprocessing
    st = time.time()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=counter1, args=(N, ))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=counter2, args=(N, ))
    
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    en = time.time()
    print("time taken = ", en - st)
```

**whose output i am getting like --**

time taken =  0.10938787460327148.

*Can someone tell me what is wrong in this code ? and in any other code i am trying multiprocessing, the kernel itself doesn't execute. Don't know what the problem is. Please help.*

Comment: What is your platform and are you running this under any special environment other than a command prompt, e.g. Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I am running this on Jupyter Notebook only.

Comment: Your Process targets need to be in another module that gets imported.